# Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `applied`

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I'm rendering a styled component defined by

```
const FilterIcon = styled(TbFilter)<{ applied: boolean }>(({applied}) => ({
  color: applied ? 'transparent' : colors.blue[500],
  fill: applied ? fillLinearGradient(colors.blue[300], colors.blue[500]) : undefined,
}))
```

like

```
  return (
    <>
      <IconButton>
        <FilterIcon fontSize={ICON_SIZE} applied={applied} />
      </IconButton>
      {childrens}
    </>
  )
```

where `applied` is a boolean defaulted to `false`.

But React is complaining

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `applied`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: applied="false" or applied={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with applied={condition && value}, pass applied={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
```

Does Emotion support non-string props?

EDIT:

Changing to

```
const FilterIcon = styled(TbFilter)<{ $applied: boolean }>`
  color: ${(props) => props.$applied ? 'transparent' : colors.blue[500]};
  fill: ${(props) => props.$applied ? fillLinearGradient(colors.blue[300], colors.blue[500]) : undefined};
`

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton>
        <FilterIcon fontSize={ICON_SIZE} $applied={applied}/>
      </IconButton>
      {childrens}
    </>
  )
```

gives me

```
Warning: Invalid attribute name: `$applied`
```

Comment: You need to check shouldForwardProps https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial mine is a different case I guess, I'm not passing the `applied` value directly into an attribute

Answer (score 1):

styled components pass attributes to dom

if your variable start with `$` its prevent to passing to dom

try to replace `applied` with `$applied` in entire code.

Comment: So besides `color` and `fill`, is `applied` passed to the rendered component in the DOM?

Comment: The special syntax starting with a dollar is a feature of styled-components. The similar library Emotion doesn't support this feature unfortunately.

Comment: did you read this  https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2822041/someone-special

```
const FilterIcon = styled(TbFilter, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => !prop.startsWith('$'),
})<{ $applied: boolean }>(({ $applied }) => ({
  color: $applied ? 'transparent' : colors.blue[500],
  fill: $applied
    ? fillLinearGradient(colors.blue[300], colors.blue[500])
    : undefined,
}))
```